Initialization order of inherited constructors
I have this example:
#include <iostream>
#define print(X) std::cout << X << std::endl

struct B1 {
    B1(int _i = 5): i(_i) { print("B1 constructor"); };
    int i;
};

struct B2 {
    B2(int _j = 7): j(_j) { print("B2 constructor"); }
    int j;
};

struct D : B2, B1 {
    using B1::B1;
};

int main(void)
{
    D d = D{10};
    print("B1::i = " << d.i);
    print("B2::j = " << d.j);
}

The output of this program is:
B2 constructor
B1 constructor
B1::i = 10
B2::j = 7

Per §11.9.4[class.inhctor.init]/1:

When a constructor for type B is invoked to initialize an object of a
different type D (that is, when the constructor was inherited
([namespace.udecl])), initialization proceeds as if a defaulted
default constructor were used to initialize the D object and each base
class subobject from which the constructor was inherited, except that
the B subobject is initialized by the inherited constructor if the
base class subobject were to be initialized as part of the D object
([class.base.init]). The invocation of the inherited constructor,
including the evaluation of any arguments, is omitted if the B
subobject is not to be initialized as part of the D object. The
complete initialization is considered to be a single function call; in
particular, unless omitted, the initialization of the inherited
constructor's parameters is sequenced before the initialization of any
part of the D object.

Firstly, per §11.9.4/1, since D inherits constructor B1(int) from base B1, that inherited constructor can initialize subobject B1; further, the parameter _i is fully initialized before initializing any part of D, hence the inherited constructor D::B1(int) is selected by overload resolution which initializes B1::i members by mem-initializer-list.
Since B2 constructor is printed first, this means that B2 constructor is called before B1. So how member B2::j is initialized with default argument 7 not value 10 that's passed in the call D{10}?
I'm not sure whether that happened, but I can't understand the sequence of execution in this case. and where this behavior is necessary in the standard.

I'm having a hard time understanding the problem, your description seems to mix B1 and B2 (or i and j), could you edit ? Also:"But, The output of this program indicates that B1(int) constructor is called first to initialize member i with 10" how does the output indicate this ?
I don't really see an issue with this program, it just calls parent constructors in the order of inheritance and calls the overriden constructor with the correct param

It works exactly as the output says - first the B2 subobject is (default-)initialized, then the B1 constructor is passed 10. The B2 is initialized first because it is mentioned first in the list of base classes.

I think the question would be easier to understand if you show the expected output, and explain why you expect it. Adding your explanation is good, but 4 lines of output is much clearer than lots of text

That is, it behaves pretty much as if D had the constructor D(int x): B2(), B1(x) {}.

@molbdnilo The B2 is initialized first because it is mentioned first in the list of base classes - So how member B1::i is initialized before B2 subobject ?

Side note, don't use macros. Use function templats in C++

It is also good practice to make single argument constructors explicit, and using multiple inheritance like this is a design flaw. So bascially you run into issue because of applying some bad practices together.

So how member B1::i is initialized before B2 subobject ? Why do you think this happens? From your exposed output, the B2::B2 is called first, as it should.

@Scheff'sCat Why do you think this happens? because member i is initialized first with value 10 - may be this mean, D d = D{10} calls B1 ctor first to initialize i with 10

@mada Again: why do you believe i is initialized first? There is nothing in the output to suggest that it is.

both constructors are default constructors, because they can be called without arguments. Not sure what your misunderstanding actually is, so I am just trying to guess.

"may be this mean, D d = D{10} calls B1 ctor first to initialize i with 10..." No, B2's ctor is used first. This is seen from the first line of the output.

i is always initialized to 10 as long as B1::B1(10) is called. You get the same output regardless of whether the constructor is executed first or last.

@user12002570 No, B2's ctor is used first. - So why j initialized with value 7 not 10 ? - calling B2 first will initialize B2::j with 10

Note that default ctor are not actually inherited at all with using before c++17.

@mada the value of j is 7 because B2 constructor is called to set it to the value, as you requires via the using declaration. The order in which the subclasses are constructed is determined by the order you put them into the class. Switch B1 and B2 in the class declaration and the print order will reverse.

Read the comment above by molbdnilo again, "That is, it behaves pretty much as if D had the constructor D(int x): B2(), B1(x) {}.". B2 is called first, but 10 is passed to B1. It seems you are confusing the way parameters are passed with the chronological order they are called.

@user12002570 - let me know the order of initializing those members

Correcting myself, the construction is more close to D(int x): B2(7), B1(x) {}, since the caller fills in default arguments. (But the order in the initialization list doesn't matter, only the order in struct D : B2, B1 does.)

@mada I get your question and what you're asking here. You're asking that if B2's ctor is called first then why isn't 10 used to initialize j. That is, why isn't j equal to 10.

@user12002570 - Yes that's what I'm trying to understand

That question may be worth answering, but things like "The output of this program indicates that the B1(int) constructor is first to initialize member i with 10." is just wrong. I suggest editing to clarify.

@mada I do have the answer. It is given in your quoted reference only. Let me write an answer explaining your quote in my answer.

I was hesitant to remove that paragraph but since you have removed it yourself I think the question now is fine and I will upvote it.

if you do not explcitily call the constructor of a base, then it is initialized by a default constructor. You do not explicitly call B2 constructor. Perhaps removing the argument, and turn it into B2(): j(7) { print("B2 constructor"); } will help to clarify your misunderstanding. That is effectively what is called

@mada Basically which class' ctor you inherit will use the D's ctor parameter as argument for it's own ctor's parameter. In your example, this means that D's ctor parameter will be passed as argument to B1's ctor. If you were instead inherit the B2 ctor then D's ctor parameter will be used as argument to B2's ctor as explained in my answer

or remove the default and you'll get an error : B2(int _j): j(42) { print("B2 constructor"); }


but I can't understand the sequence of execution

The important thing here is that the "only" the inherited ctor(B1::B1() here) will use the D's ctor's parameter to initialize its data member.
This here means that since you've inherited B1's ctor, the parameter _i in the ctor D::D(int _i) will be passed as an argument to initialize i of the B1 subobject.
Baiscally, your code class' D is equivalent to writing:
struct D : public B2, public B1
{
  inline D(int _i) 
  : B2(7)
//--vvvvvv------------->this is because you inherited B1's ctor
  , B1(_i)
  {
  }
  
};

This is given in your quoted class.inhctor.init only which has been highlighted:

When a constructor for type B is invoked to initialize an object of a different type D (that is, when the constructor was inherited ([namespace.udecl])), initialization proceeds as if a defaulted default constructor were used to initialize the D object and each base class subobject from which the constructor was inherited, except that the B subobject is initialized by the inherited constructor if the base class subobject were to be initialized as part of the D object ([class.base.init]).
The invocation of the inherited constructor, including the evaluation of any arguments, is omitted if the B subobject is not to be initialized as part of the D object.The complete initialization is considered to be a single function call; in particular, unless omitted, the initialization of the inherited constructor's parameters is sequenced before the initialization of any part of the D object.

(emphasis mine)

You can additionally verify this by inheriting B2's ctor by doing using B2::B2. Then your class D will be equivalent to:
struct D : public B2, public B1
{
  inline D(int _j)
//--vvvvvv------------>this happens when you inherit B2's ctor
  : B2(_j)
  , B1(5)
  {
  }
  
};


Thanks for your answer. Something relatively irrelevant: In the given quote: "... if the base class subobject were to be initialized as part of the D object ..." -  Why if here? I mean, is there a case where the base subobject is not initialized as part of derived D?

@mada There may be some edge case. But I'm not seeing any edge case possible here. Maybe a new question for this follow up question would be better. You're welcome. Maybe someone else will answer that.

@mada Virtual inheritance.

This is expected. Note that to construct D you have to call constructors for all ancestors, so this means B1 and B2. Order of invoking those constructors is enforced by order of inheritance list. Not this is old C++ rule which has to be maintained forever.
So when D is constructed default constructor for B2 is called then constructor for B1 is called with argument you have passed to it.
Better demo:
#include <print>
#include <source_location>

void log(int val, const std::source_location& from, const std::source_location& loc = std::source_location::current())
{
    std::println("{}:{} val={} invoked from: {}:{}", loc.function_name(), loc.line(), val, from.function_name(), from.line());
}

struct B1 {
    B1(int _i = 5, const std::source_location& loc = std::source_location::current())
        : i(_i)
    {
        log(i, loc);
    };
    int i;
};

struct B2 {
    B2(int _j = 7, const std::source_location& loc = std::source_location::current())
        : j(_j)
    {
        log(j, loc);
    }
    int j;
};

struct D : B2, B1 {
    using B1::B1;
};

int main(void)
{
    D d = D { 10 };
    std::println("B1::i = {}", d.i);
    std::println("B2::j = {}", d.j);
}

Log output:
B2::B2(int, const std::source_location &):22 val=7 invoked from: D::B1(int, const std::source_location &):28
B1::B1(int, const std::source_location &):13 val=10 invoked from: int main():33
B1::i = 10
B2::j = 7

Note that compiler created constructor which is called: D::B1!


The output of this program indicates that B1(int) constructor is called first to initialize member i with 10. Then before the body of B1(int) is executed, and I don't know how the execution sequence is jumped to B2(int)

How do you arrive at this conclusion? The output of the program indicates only two things:

Constructor B2 ran before constructor B1
When you instantiated D{10}, constructor B1 was selected to be passed that argument, via the using expression in D's class body.

I don't know what the standard says specifically about the order of initialization when inheriting from multiple independant base classes (and I don't want to make assumptions here that may be incorrect), but your program works in a way I would expect it to.

"I don't know what the standard says specifically..." The question is language-lawyered. So this doesn't actually answer the question.

The question quotes the relevant section from the standard
